# Symfony - Changing how controllers are instantiated and executed

Tags: php, symfony

> *Note:* as of version 2.8, Symfony provided `autowire: true` for service configuration, and as of version 3.3, Symfony provided `alias` (instead of `autowire_types`) to alias a concrete object to an interface for automatic dependency injection into 'controllers as services'. There's also a bundle to allow autowiring for controller 'action' methods, although I've moved away from this and have focussed more on a variation of the ADR pattern (which is, basically, a single 'action' class with an interface method and not shoving a load of actions methods within a single class which eventually makes for an architectural nightmare). This is, effectively, what I've been looking for all these years and now no longer need to 'hook-in' a decent recursive dependency injector (auryn) as the framework now handles what it should have four years previous. I'll leave this answer here in case anyone wants to trace the steps that I did to see how the kernel works and some of the options available at this level.

---

> Note: Although this question primarily targets Symfony 3, it should also be relevant to users of Symfony 2 as the kernel logic doesn't seem to have changed much.

I want to change how controllers are instantiated in Symfony. The logic for their instantiation currently resides in [HttpKernel::handle](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/HttpKernel.php#L57) and, more specifically, [HttpKernel::handleRaw](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/HttpKernel.php#L139). I want to replace `call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments)` with my own injector performing that specific line instead.

The options I have tried thus far:

- Extending `HttpKernel::handle` with my own method and then having this called by symfony

```
http_kernel:
    class: AppBundle\HttpKernel
    arguments: ['@event_dispatcher', '@controller_resolver', '@request_stack']
```

The downside of this is that, because `handleRaw` is private, I can't extend it without hacky reflection and so I would have to copy and paste a tonne of code.

- Creating and registering a new controller resolver

```
controller_resolver:
    class: AppBundle\ControllerResolver
    arguments: []
```

This was a fundamental misunderstanding I had so I thought I'd document it here. The resolver's job is to resolve *where* to find the controller as a callable. It hasn't actually been called yet. I am more than happy with how Symfony takes the routes from `routes.yml` and figures out the class and method to call for the controller as a callable.

- Adding an event listener on `kernel.request`

```
kernel.request:
    class: MyCustomRequestListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 33 /** Important, we'll get to why in a minute **/ }
```

Taking a look at the [Http Kernel Component Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event), we can see that it has the following typical purpose:

> To add more information to the Request, initialise parts of the system, or return a Response if possible (e.g. a security layer that denies access).

I figured that by creating a new listener, using my custom injector to create my controller, and then return a response in that listener, would bypass the rest of the code that instantiates the controller. **This is what I want**! But there's a major flaw with this:

*The Symfony Profiler doesn't show up or any of that stuff, it's just my response and that's it. Dead.* I found that I can switch the priority from 31 to 33 and have it switch between my code and Symfonys, and I believe this is because of the router listener [priority](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-request). I feel I'm going down the wrong path here.

- Listening on the [kernel.controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-controller-event) event.

No, this allows me to change the **callable** that will be called by `call_user_func_array()`, not how the controller is actually instantiated, which is my goal.

I've documented my ideas but I'm out. How can I achieve the following?

- Change how the controllers are instantiated and then executed, specifically `call_user_func_array()` which is in a bloody private method (thanks Symfony)
- Fall back to the default controller instantiation if mine doesn't work
- Allow everything else to work as expected, like the profiler loading
- Be able to bundle this up with an extension for other users

---

**Why** do I want to do this?

Controllers can have many different methods for different circumstances and each method should be able to typehint for what it individually requires rather than having a constructor take all the things, some of which may not even be used depending on the controller method being executed. Controllers don't *really* adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle, and they're an 'object edge case'. But they are what they are.

I want to replace how controllers are created with my own recursively autowiring injector, and also how they are executed, again with recursive introspection via my injector, as the default Symfony package does not seem to have this functionality. Even with the latest "autowire" service option in Symfony 2.8+.

Comment: I couln't imagine the big table but reflection may be a key point to override that private method. http://blag.kazeno.net/development/access-private-protected-properties this article may help you.

Comment: @FeyyazEsatoğlu My first bullet point explains how I didn't want to use reflection (I have tried that already and didn't like it).

Comment: oops, sorry I missed that.

Comment: Could you tell us what do you wan't to achieve? Why don't you want to use the "standard way"? Maybe there's another approach/tool to solve your problem.

Comment: Because I want to use a [specific](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn) recursively auto-wiring dependency injector instead of Symfonys container that requires manual registration of all concrete objects. Also, Symfony's new one in 2.8 doesn't allow the aliasing of concretes to abstracts as far as I can see.

Comment: Also, auto-wiring for controller method calls, not just controller constructors, is something I gain here.

Comment: If I may, you should add these last comments in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that - it may help with added context.

Answer (score 1):

The controller resolver actually does two things.  The first is to get the controller.  The second is to get a list of arguments for a given action.

```
$arguments = $this->resolver->getArguments($request, $controller);
$response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
```

It is the getArguments method that you could override to implement your special "action method injection" functionality.  You just need to determine what arguments the action method needs and return an array of them.

Based on a different question, I also think you might be misunderstanding the autowire functionality.  Autowire really only applies to constructor injection.  It's not going to help with action method injection.

If the getArguments does not solve your requirement then overriding the handle method is really your only option.  Yes there is quite a bit of code to copy/paste from handleRaw but that is because there is quite a bit to do in there.  And even if handleRaw was protected you would still have to copy/paste the code just to get at the one line you want to replace.

Comment: Autowiring can certainly happen on method calls. If a method typehints for a concrete object, the process of obtaining the name of that object via introspection and instantiating it is the same process used for the constructor instead. I am currently looking at the handleRaw override though. Not nice, but possible.

Comment: If you say so.  When you do figure out how to get the Symfony container to autowire a method call then please post an example.

Comment: That's the part I'm trying to figure out. There's a crossover between the kernel handle method that instantiates the controller and the resolver which figures out arguments. There will be some way :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return your own callable from custom `ControllerResolverInterface` that would instantiate `Controller` in a way you want and call it?

It would be basically a decorator.

You can extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver` with your own implementation of `instantiateController()` method, or you can implement `ControllerResolverInterface` from the scratch.

UPD:

When Symfony makes a `call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);` call in `handleRaw()`, the `$controller` variable is what you've returned from your custom `ControllerResolver`. That means you can return any callable from your resolver (it can be `[$this, "callController"]` f.e.) and inside this callable you would create a new `Controller` with Auryn and call it.

UPD2:

If you're still struggling with this, I'll add an example because you might miss what I meant here.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver;

class AutowiringControllerResolver extends ControllerResolver
{
    // ... constructor stuff; assume $injector is a part of this class

    protected function createController($controller)
    {
        $controller = parent::createController($controller);

        return function (...$arguments) use ($controller) {
            // you can do with resolved $arguments whatever you want
            // or you can override getArguments() method and return
            // empty array to discard getArguments() functionality completely

            return $this->injector->execute($controller);
        };
    }

    protected function instantiateController($classname)
    {
        return $this->injector->make($classname);
    }
}
```

Comment: A decorator as in: `function() use ($controller) { return $controller; }`? That's a callable. Problem is I need to have the controller `execute()`d (if you know the Auryn API), so I still have to pass it the method to be auto-resolved as well.

Comment: For example from `ControllerResolverInterface#getController` you'd return `function () use ($class, $method, $injector) { return $injector->execute([$class, $method]); }` Wouldn't it work for your case?

Comment: So `getController` needs to return a callable just for the controller itself, which means Auryn is handling the constructor via `make()`. I need to also handle the controller method **being called** via `execute`, which is the `call_user_func()` call doing that.

Comment: I added an update to the answer, tell me if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Listener is too late to solve your needs, since it excludes Dependency Injection container, which is  crucial to create a valid object (~= service).

You are probably looking for Controller Autowiring feature.

If that's so, you might find solution or at least inspiration in this bundle: http://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2016/03/10/autowired-controllers-as-services-for-lazy-people/

It meets your needs in these points:

- autowire injector
- fallback to default (FrameworkBundle's) controller resolver, if not found
- it also should keep all the flow working, since there are no hacks during controller resolving process